# How to remove a modified file from a Github PR from the UI (not CLI)

Tags: github

There are plenty of answers for how to remove a modified file from a PR using `git` commands on the CLI, but it sure would be nice to be able to do so directly through the GitHub UI.

Right now, it looks like you only have the option to "Delete file" from the UI:
[GitHub three-dot file submenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6243v.png)

Seems like there should also be a `Revert file` or something. Is this feature just missing, or is it I who am missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this feature exists, but I'll tell you that most reasonably senior developers do tend to edit these things with either the Git command line or the integration in their editors, so most of these more complicated features are less likely to be implemented for that reason.